# Facebook SDK 6.4 c# get email using LoginButton

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I´ve added permitions to get the user email and I can't access the email returned in the GraphObject using the LogginButton.CurrentUser

how can I get access to the email field returned within he facebook login response?

Something like LogginButton.CurrentUser.Email ( I know that this isn't possible since GraphUser doe not contain a Email property. How can I get the email information?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i had to do this to get the email in the loginButton_UserInfoChanged event:
FacebookSessionClient fsc = new FacebookSessionClient(appid);
            var session = await fsc.LoginAsync();
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);
            dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync("me");

and then get the value using result.email

Comment: this way it is making 2 requests to facebook... and that's not what i want. anyone please?